# Converting From XML to Docx with Docx4j

Tags: java, xml, docx4j

I am using the Java Docx4j library to convert a .docx file to its .xml representation, store the XML in a database, and then convert the XML back to a .docx file.

So far I can successfully convert the .docx file to XML and store it in the database. However I am having issues converting that XML back into the .docx form. I am not editing the XML in anyway. If I open the XML file in Word it displays fine.

```
String inputFilePath = args[0];
WordprocessingMLPackage wmlPackage = Docx4J.load(new File(inputFilePath));

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Docx4J.save(wmlPackage, baos, Docx4J.FLAG_SAVE_FLAT_XML);

DatabaseController databaseController = new DatabaseController();
databaseController.commitXMLToDatabase(baos, "file-sample_1MB"); // Add the XML and filename to DB

String xml = databaseController.retrieveDocument("file-sample_1MB");

// Issue with the code below:
WordprocessingMLPackage testPkg = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();
testPkg.getMainDocumentPart().unmarshal(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
testPkg.save(new File("src/main/resources/test1.docx"));
```

I get the error below (I have removed some of the Scheme URLs listed)

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
 - with linked exception:
[javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 133; unexpected element (uri:"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage", local:"package"). Expected elements are <{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel}ClientData>,<{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/spreadsheetDrawing}wsDr>,<{}xml>,<{http://opendope.org/xpaths}xpath>,<{http://opendope.org/conditions}xpathref>,<{http://opendope.org/xpaths}xpaths>,<{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}yearLong>,<{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}yearShort>]]
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.JaxbXmlPartXPathAware.unmarshal(JaxbXmlPartXPathAware.java:586)
    at org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.JaxbXmlPartXPathAware.unmarshal(JaxbXmlPartXPathAware.java:346)
    at DocxToXML.main(DocxToXML.java:37)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I can post the .docx and .xml files if they would be of any help.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it now. The code I am using now is the following:

```
// retrieveDocument() gets the data from DB Blob as a byte[] Array 
// and returns an InputStream
InputStream xml = databaseController.retrieveDocument("Test1"); 
WordprocessingMLPackage pkg = Docx4J.load(xml);
Docx4J.save(pkg, new File("src/main/resources/output/test1.docx"));
```